# Implementing similar UseCases looks like code duplication

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have the following case. User can export several object types (transaction, invoice, etc) to external accounting system.
Export algorithm has steps:

- fetch objects by some filter
- export objects one by one to the accounting system (web service method per object type)
- register the fact that given document was exported, so it wont be exported again
- prepare summary for user (num of exported documents, error messages etc)

The algorithm is the same for all object types but there are some important differences which must be handled:

- different types
- different target web service method, different object to DTO mappings
- different filters per object type

I've considered a few solutions:

- don't treat the export algorithm as code duplication and implement an algorithm per object type. Export of any data to any external system may be described by such algorithm - does it mean that we should always have one general class to export anything to anywhere?:)
- move the differences to strategies (one strategy interface to create abstraction for all differences) - I even implemented it.
- use generics - unfortunately I'm coding in PHP and it's not possible

**The question:**

Is creating a separate export algorithm per object type a code duplication?

Maybe all of them should be treated as separate Use Cases?

If it's a duplication then what techniques to avoid it should I consider?

**Description of my first implementation:**

In first approach I defined an Exportable abstraction but I was not happy about it. Each object has completely different payload. 
An Exportable interface defined only one method getId and it was used to register that object was exported (and thanks to that wont be exported again).
For this purpose the abstraction was fine, but the problem was moved to exportService which had to check the concrete instance to choose DTO mapper and endpoint. So the exportService broke SOLID.

Comment: Very good question. Did you take *«include»* and *«extend»* relationships between your use cases into account? They would probably help here. Also some pattern like *Framework*, *Extensibility* or *Template Method* could be an alternative to your implementation approaches.

Comment: First, you should view filtering and exporting as two different problems. You usually want to move the differences to strategies and then hide the strategies selection behind a Facade/Factory depending on the way your API is designed. For instance, the client might only do `exportService.export(listOfExportable)`, but internally based on the type of `Exportable`, a web service endpoint will be chosen as well as a dto assembler. The export service could be made configurable from the outside to avoid violating the open-closed principle. You could also put the strategy selection on the Exportable

Comment: The advantage of letting the exportable specify the strategies would let you avoid using the service locator pattern within the export service. The exportService could just double-dispatch on the `Exportable` to gather the information. At the same time, there's a disadvantage since infrastructure concerns could be leaked in layers where they shouldn't. This is a similar struggle to "should I put ORM annotations in an entity or should I use external XML files?".

Comment: Template Method is a pattern that sounds like it might apply here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @plalx I've added description of my first approach with creating of an abstraction "Exportable" and why it failed.
Going back to your comment. Do you mean to wrap objects to some concrete Exportable implementation where Exportable has only export method and all the differences are hidden there?

Comment: @JakubFilipczyk `Exportable` could have a contract which makes it easier to resolve the correct endpoint and mapper for an exporting service or it might even offer a method to get the exportable representation. You might have to find the right balance between being a purist about not leaking infrastructure details in the domain and being practical for the implementation. Sometimes, compromises needs to be made (e.g. using a layer supertype to give an id to value objects so they can be persisted by an ORM).

Comment: Note that I am not saying the entity should know how to export itself, but might know how to create an exportable representation of itself, not directly, but by delegating to the right DTO assembler internally. However, you will have to determine if it's worst to use the service locator anti-pattern within ExportService or to leak a bit of infrastructure details in the domain... @guillaume31 any input on this?

Answer (score 0):

None of the things you have described above are domain-specific logic (and in fact you don't even mention the problem domain in your question), so I don't think it really falls under domain-driven design.  Because it's not domain-specific logic I wouldn't worry too much about code duplication, especially considering that the solution doesn't seem obvious.

**Keep it simple and just write out each use case separately.  If you find that there's common code that's easily refactored, do so after you get everything working smooth.  Don't overthink it or add patterns before they are obviously necessary.**

Comment: It could be a subdomain of his main domain. *"Register the fact that given document was exported, so it wont be exported again"* is domain logic IMO.